# ASP.NET core load connection string

Tags: heroku, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm building an ASP.NET Core 2 application. I want to deploy my application to Heroku, however, I need to load the connection string from their environment variable $DATABASE_URL. In my `startup.cs` I have:

```cs
namespace LearningSystems
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            });

            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            });

            SetupDbContext(services);
        }

        private void SetupDbContext(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            var conn = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("$DATABASE_URL");
            var connectionString =  Configuration.GetConnectionString("pmf");

            services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
                .AddDbContext<pmf_visualizationsContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseSession();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Home",
                    template: "",
                    defaults: new {controller = "Shell", action = "Index"}
                );
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I want to load a different connection string when I am in a production environment (Heroku). 
However, in the method SetupDbContext, I don't know how to find out in which environment I am located. Can anyone tell me what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using IHostingEnvironment and Getting the current environment.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments)

[Kindly refer to this link for help]